# Thunk Action Body not being Invoked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

My thunk action doesn't seem to be running through its core logic.  I tall the thunk action from `componentDidMount` but it doesn't in turn cause this to run: `const response = await findOne(id)`.

Also, I thought I didn't need to explicitely pass dispatch as a prop to mapDispatchToProps if using redux-thunk, I thought that the way I have my thunk setup is that dispatch is available already to the thunk?  And I've used other actions like this and it's worked fine, why not this one?

**Thunk Action**

```
export function fetchCompany(id) {
  return async (dispatch) => {

    try {
      const response = await findOne(id)

      if(response && response.body) {
        const company = response.body
        dispatch(companyReceived(company))
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("failed request in authenticate thunk action")
      console.log(`error details: ${err.status} /n ${err}`)
    }
  }
}
```

**Container**
......

```
import { fetchCompany } from '../../client/actions/company/CompanyAsyncActions'

class InterviewContainer extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    await fetchCompany(this.props.params.companyId)
  }

  render(){
    return (this.props.company && <Interview className='ft-interview' company={this.props.company} />)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  company: state.company.company
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchCompany: fetchCompany
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InterviewContainer)
```

In the past, I haven't passed (dispatch) as a prop to mapDispatchToProps and it worked fine.  But I see everyone else is doing so.  How was my code working in the past if I wasn't doing that?  And why isn't this working this time around in the example above?

Taking a look at **another async action thunk container and call example**, this is working completely fine, and I'm calling it the same way in another container

**container**

```
class HomePageContainer extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.fetchFeaturedCompanies()
    await this.props.fetchCompanies()
    await this.props.fetchCountries()
  }

  render(){
    return (<HomePage className='ft-homepage'
                      featuredCompanies={this.props.featuredCompanies}
                      countries={this.props.countries}
                      companies={this.props.companies}
    />)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  countries: state.country.countries,
  companies: state.company.companies,
  featuredCompanies: state.company.featuredCompanies
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchCountries: fetchCountries,
  fetchCompanies: fetchCompanies,
  fetchFeaturedCompanies: fetchFeaturedCompanies
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePageContainer)
```

**thunk action**

```
export function fetchCompanies() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const response = await find()

    if(response && response.body) {
      const companies = response.body
      dispatch(companiesReceived(companies))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you pass an object of functions as the `mapDispatchToProps` parameter of `connect`, each function is wrapped in `dispatch` so your `mapDispatchToProps` is not the issue. See the [docs on connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `componentDidMount` of `InterviewContainer` you're accidentally calling the imported `fetchCompany`, instead of `this.props.fetchCompany`.

Comment: yes I'm an idiot, I _just_ fond that too.  Ugh.  Thanks